# Determining remotely which local PCs have updated to Window 10 Anniversary Update?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607

My company has a variety of PC hardware with Windows 10 installed.  However, few of them have received the Windows 10 Anniversary Update.  How can I tell which of them has Received the 1607 update remotely?
We're not using WSUS or any other update management at this time.

Comment: `psexec \\computername winver`. If the version number is `1607` or greater, then you have the Anniversary Update installed.

Comment: Just run "winver" or check the update history and look up the kb numbers